# Enable views for user in sql server 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a user in my SQL server who shall only be able to select from views in a certain schema.
However the database does not appear in the tree folder, and hence not the Views folder.
Is there a way to enable the display of these in the tree structure without granting access to the DB itself?

```
CREATE SCHEMA [gib]
GO

CREATE USER [GibUser] FOR LOGIN [GibUser] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[gib]
GO

CREATE VIEW [gib].[MyLocalData]
AS
       SELECT TOP 10 * FROM DBData
GO

GRANT select on [gib].[MyLocalData] TO GibUser
```

Comment: How do you expect someone to access an object within a database if you aren't going to let them access the database?

Comment: Well, I'm new to SQL server, so what I want may not be possible.
The user has access to the DB through a number of views, and I wanted the list of views to be visible in the SQL server management studio.

Comment: Yes, but they still need access to the db or they won't be able to connect.